# How to show Admob ads with different ad ids once different tabs are selected in Android?

Tags: admob, android-tabactivity

At present, I'm using only one ad id and refreshing the ad after 30secs using a thread since its a Double Click ad and showing the same ad when any of the tabs are selected and showing the ads above the tabs.
I have a requirement to show ads with different ad ids when each tab is selected. I have 4 tabs and 4 ad ids. When I click the 1st tab I need to show the ads coming from the 1st ad id, when I click the 2nd tab the ads should come from the 2nd id and so on. Also, when a new tab is clicked the previous ad which was shown when the previous tab was clicked needs to be removed and the ad coming from the ad id with respect to the current tab needs to be loaded. The refreshing of the ads too needs to happen accordingly in each tab. Could you please let me know if there is any way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using different ad ids requires different AdView instances. One way to do this is to have 4 AdViews, and listen for Android's callback when the selected tab changes to determine which ad should be set to VISIBLE and which ones should be set to NONE. Your refresh logic can poll for the current tab, and refresh the AdView corresponding to that tab.